# One Wordpress Installation for 2 Domains

Tags: customization, multisite, domain, domain-mapping

I've completed my wordpress page with a few subpages and one domain xyz.de. So I've a couple of pages, let's assume:

> xyz.de
>
> xyz.de/page1
>
> xyz.de/specific_topic

Right now, my second domain **specific_topic.de** redirects to **xyz.de/specific_topic**. I'm wondering whether it would be possible to keep the domain **specific_topic.de** in the addressbar of the browser, so when entering **specific_topic.de**, I want to see exactly the page which is right now shown when visiting **xyz.de/specific_topic**. There wouldn't be any subpages for **specific_topic.de**; it would JUST ONLY SHOW that single page. All the other menu items would again link to the original domain **xyz.de**.

So I want to get rid of the hard redirect, but instead keep the domain. This domain wouldn't have any further subpages, it's really just this domain for this one page named "specific_topic".

Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried WordPress Multisite install? https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This free plugin seems to be exactly for what you want, and is up to date: https://wordpress.org/plugins/multiple-domain-mapping-on-single-site/

You will need to point the DNS A record of the second domain to the same IP as the main one. There are more instructions in the FAQ section of the page I linked.

This is NOT for a multisite. It is for a single WordPress installation with multiple domains.

Comment: it is not for multisite, it is not for woocommerse, you will have problems with admin and CORS, and it might just not work if you have some shitty code that do not generate URLs the wy the plugin expects. In addition to the plugin being a huge hit and miss by its own description, answers that are basically a link to a non canonical external resources are not much of an answer, and better be left as comments

Comment: @MarkKaplun What are you talking about? He never said woocommerce or multisite and the answer is not just a link. As far as I see I am giving him exactly what he wanted.

Comment: "What he wanted" is not a great attribute for answers around here. Can other people read this answer and learn anything from it? is much more important. If for example a guy with WC want to do the same, will your answer be helpful to him?. And you don't even know the OP do not use WC.

Comment: Neither do I have a multisite, not any WooCommerce, dunno even what it is. And the link nikolay posted seems to be exactly what I want, 100% hit. I'll check when I'm back home whether it works for my links or not, I'd not than I might just skip the idea of there's no easier built in way of doing so (@mark: or do you have a solution instead of just being negative)? Thanks nikolay, and Mark, I found this post quite fitting to your comments: http://eng.marksw.com/2016/03/12/not-being-nice-andor-constructive-is-very-important-is-software-development/ 

Comment: And one more thing: if a user posts a link to something which helps me for MY QUESTION, this is exactly what the site is for. I simply asked for a solution and he offered me one

Comment: lol @tim are you serious? what have you ever contributed anywhere except for freeloading of other peoples work and than complaining about it?

Comment: With the major difference being that I don't complain like this. But nevermind. This will not lead anywhere.

Comment: @tim I am glad it was useful for you. I guess Mark is trying to push people to do better answers, and he has contributed more than both of us on other topics (seeing his reputation) but pretty weird to want the answer to include things that are not even asked, if you ask me. Anyway. Regards to both.